# Проблемы с Vk комментариями

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, pagespeed-insights

Vk просит вставлять код в head документа, но Google Page speed ругается и пишет :"Удалите из верхней части страницы код JavaScript и CSS, блокирующий отображение".Удалив из head код ,сайт действительно стал лучше грузится - было 60 стало 70. Но если убрать код виджета из head, то комментарии не грузятся, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Боюсь, никак не решить, и придётся смириться с некоторым подтормаживанием (не думаю, что оно критичное). В принципе, PageSpeed Insights — вспомогательный инструмент, главнее тут самому смотреть, насколько долго загружаются страницы сайта. Тормозит — придётся думать о замене или отказе от определённых элементов, нет — так ничего страшного, что результат не 100%. Спасибо.

Comment: Страница не тормозит, загружается примерно за 4 секунды.Чисто с точки зрения эстетики хочется чтобы google page speed тоже высоким был)

Comment: Ну, если вы игнорируете указания vk, то не удивительно, что работает неправильно.